# Accesing UNIX variable path in Python

Tags: python, unix

I want to access a file present in a certain location in UNIX box. Usually I use

**Path**

```
$HOME/my/path/filename
```

I am pusuing the following python code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
mytime= time.strftime("%Y%m%d", localtime)
file = $HOME/my/path/Text.$mytime*
```

I am getting the following error

```
 file = $HOME/my/path/Text.$mytime*
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

PS: Filename is of the format

> Text.YYYYMMDDhhmmss

Python Version 2.6

Comment: well, you are doing division with '/'. Path should be a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
os.environ["HOME"]
os.environ["mytime"]
```

os.environ will provide access to your environmental variables

```
file = "%s/my/path/Text%s*"%(os.environ["HOME"], os.environ["mytime"])
```

Comment: HOME is a environment variable. "mytime" is what I am calculating as shown in the code. I tried `file = "%s/my/path/Text%s*"(os.environ["TOP"], $mytime)`  but i am getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` on variavle `$mytime` which I pass along with `os.environ["TOP"]`

Comment: `"%s/my/path/Text%s*"(os.environ["TOP"], mytime)`